# Intent Google Hangouts as SMS

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I am trying to send SMS from an app. It works pretty well with the Samsung Galaxy S3 (mini) default messaging service.

But when trying to send it from Google Hangouts, it opens but doesn't load its interface; it only shows the "loading" circle…

Here's the chunk of code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
String text = new String(getResources().getString(R.string.invitation_message_sms));
text.replaceAll("TEAMNAME", teamName);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", text+currentTeam().url);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Works well on Kitkat 4.4.4 using Google Hangout as default SMS app.

```
String sms = "Message here";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + Uri.encode(phone_no)));
intent.putExtra("sms_body", sms);
startActivity(intent);
```